# Javascript prompt only reading first digit of an input number

Tags: javascript, arrays, digits

I'm working on a quick little exercise, and I am trying to allow a user to input 5 random numbers and have my script arrange them in ascending order, however it only works on single digit numbers. For example, when a user inputs 27, the program sorts it as if it were simply a 2.  I am not certain what is causing this to happen, and I am open to any suggestions. (Also, code is not as concise as possible but please overlook)

```js
let array = [];
let scrapArray = [];
array[0] = prompt("Please input a random number");
array[1] = prompt("Please input another random number");
array[2] = prompt("Please input another random number");
array[3] = prompt("Please input another random number");
array[4] = prompt("Please input another random number");
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for (let j = (i + 1); j < 5; j++) {
    if (array[i] >= array[j]) {
      scrapArray[i] = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = scrapArray[i]
    }
  }
}
console.log("the order of numbers from lowest to highest is: ");
for (let m = 0; m < array.length; m++) {
  console.log(array[m]);
}
```

Comment: You code has no problem and runs well on my computer. Could you run it on other computer?

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting strings to `array`, not numbers. The type of the returned value of `prompt()` is `string`.

Convert the input to a number.

```
  array[0]=Number(prompt("Please input a random number"));
  array[1]=Number(prompt("Please input another random number"));
  array[2]=Number(prompt("Please input another random number"));
  array[3]=Number(prompt("Please input another random number"));
  array[4]=Number(prompt("Please input another random number"));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number